# Многопоточность в телеграмм боте на Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграмм бота, функционал следующий: пользователь отдает команду на создание потока который будет в цикле выполнять некую функцию.
**Вопрос следующий, как реализовать остановку потока, если этого захотел пользователь, т.е. необходимо обратится именно к этому потоку и его остановить(в цикле будет условие, если false выйти из цикла, так думаю реализовать остановку). Так вот как идентифицировать поток и затем к нему обратиться?**

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь может изначально давать имя потоку в команде старта.

Пользователь будет использовать это имя в команде остановки.

Можно сделать `concurrent` `Map/Set`, где ключ содержит имя пользователя и потока.

Команда остановки убирает значение из мапа.

Поток проверяет значение в мапе в цикле.